# VS2013 Express Web Deployment: how to configure it on server side

Tags: web, webdeploy

I want to do publish of web-api application from VS2013Express to Windows 7 Professional. When I start publishing, the authentication fails, but my account is administrative one on server machine.

On server: WEb Deploy 3.5 is installed. But I dont see option Deploy - > Configure Web Deploy Publishing on any of my sites.
Where is the problem:)?

PS. I was following this document for Web Deploy installation/configuration:
http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later